# javascript simple countdown with refresh function

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am getting an output of 00 min NaN sec. Does anyone know what may be wrong with my code?

Desired outcome, countdown from 5min then add class 'ended'

```
using jquery.countdown.js
```

Thank you.

```
$(function() {
        var endDate = "05:00";

        $('.countdown.callback').countdown({
          date: endDate,
          render: function(data) {
            $(this.el).html("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>min</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>sec</span></div>");
          },
          onEnd: function() {
            $(this.el).addClass('ended');
          }
        }).on("click", function() {
          $(this).removeClass('ended').data('countdown').update(endDate).start();
        });

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, your endDate variable is not valid. I believe it needs to follow the JavaScript method of getting a date so you might need to do something like this

```
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 5); // Adding 5 minutes to the current time
```

Comment: Ok, but now the on.Click function isnt refreshing the countdown

Comment: You will need to do endDate = new Date(); endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 5); inside of the on click event but before $(this).removeClass line.

Comment: .on("click", function() {
          endDate = new Date(); endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 5); 
          $(this).removeClass('ended');
        });

Comment: .on("click", function() { endDate = new Date(); endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 5); $(this).removeClass('ended'); $(this).removeClass('ended').data('countdown').update(endDate).start(); });